# How to store two values from an array in one pass

Tags: javascript, python

How to replicate this code from python into javascript:

```
myList = [1,2]
a,b = myList[0], myList[1]

print(a) # output 1 
print(b) # output 2
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: @kingforever thanks, very helpful link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), by either

- taking an **array** with variables as LHS assignment, or
- taking an **object** with the wanted indices and variables by using an [object property assignment pattern [YDKJS: ES6 & Beyond]](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#object-property-assignment-pattern).

The last one is important, if you like to destructure an array with lots of elements and need just some at some index.

```js
var myList = [1, 2],
    [a, b] = myList,
    { 0: c, 1: d } = myList;

console.log(a, b);
console.log(c, d);
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use **[destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)**:

```js
let myList = [1, 2];
let [a, b] = myList;

console.log("a is: " + a);
console.log("b is: " + b);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

If you need to take some particular elements at specific indexes of the array you can do like this:

```js
let myList = [3, 5, 1, 4, 2];
let [a, b] = [myList[2], myList[4]];

console.log("a is: " + a);
console.log("b is: " + b);

// Or ...

let myList2 = [3, 5, 1, 4, 2];
let {2: c, 4: d} = myList;

console.log("c is: " + c);
console.log("d is: " + d);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const myList = [1,2]

const [a,b] = myList;

console.log(a,b)
```

This is known as array de-structuring

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring

Answer (score 1):

You can use ES6 Destructuring assignment.

```
myList = [1,2];
[value1, value2] = myList;
```

Now value1 and value2 will have 1 and 2 respectively.

Similarly,

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
[a,b,...c] = myList;
```

a and b will have 1 and 2 as their value and c will be an array containing [3,4,5,6,7,8].

Answer (score 0):

Use the snippet below.

```js
var myList = [1, 2];
var a = myList[0], b = myList[1];

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let myList = [1,2];
let a = myList[0];
let b = myList[1];
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using new es6 syntax you can do this.

```
var myList = [1,2]

var [a,b] = myList
console.log(a)
console.log(b)
```